# Establish connection to send data from web or application server to an android device

Tags: android, webserver, push-notification, push

Hello android developers,

I am an android developer, i would like to build an application that receive data from a server and display it as notification message. i am trying to create push notification services with out using GCM from google.

How can i send messages to a particular android device from my web/application server and how can i find the android device to send data for that particular device without using GCM.

Your helpful suggestions will be appreciated greatly.

Thanks in advance.

Sathish

Answer (score 0):

Google is first of all. But use [GCM](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/), it's Google's push notifications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have tried using GCM but it is very slow and is a beta version. If you can verify Urbanairship.com it is providing push notification service with GCM and without GCM, so i would like to implement the same without using GCM. Please suggest me in that way.

Comment: GCM is no longer beta, the beta was C2DM - Cloud to device messaging. Have no idea about Urbanairship, don't even know if Android is supported from what i read. but it's really up to you.